# find works, but find -exec doesn’t

Tags: macos, shell, find, args

I am trying to find all images in subfolders of a given folder, and move them somewhere else. I have tried the following in `zsh` (my default) and `sh` (what most tutorials seem to be using) on a Mac running OS X 10.9.3.

This prints out all the images in the subfolders of `$someDir`:

```
find "$someDir" -iname \*.jpg -o -name \*.png -o -name \*.gif
```

However, when I want to pass those images to another command, I can’t get it to work. As an exercise, I tried it with `echo`:

```
find "$someDir" -iname \*.jpg -o -name \*.png -o -name \*.gif -exec sh -c "echo hello {}" \;
```

It just returns silently, and the value of `$?` is `0`.

I eventually want to do something along these lines:

```
find "$someDir" -iname \*.jpg -o -name \*.png -o -name \*.gif -exec sh -c "mv {} $destination" \;
```

But I can‘t even get the `echo` example to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry if I tagged this wrong. `find` and `args` didn’t quite seem right, but they were the best I could find.

Comment: The `sh -c mv ...` is pointless.  Just `-exec mv {} $destination \;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put parentheses around all the name tests:

```
find "$someDir" \( -iname \*.jpg -o -name \*.png -o -name \*.gif \) -exec sh -c "echo hello {}" \;
```

Otherwise, the `-exec` is only done for files that match `*.gif`.

When you leave out the action, there's a default `-print` in each branch of the `-o`. But if there's any action option in the command, there's no default actions anywhere.

Comment: Perfect! The reason I couldn’t tell what was going on is that I don’t have any GIFs in the folder in question. Thanks!

Comment: I had the opposite problem. I tried running your version, and it produced lots of output, so I thought there was no problem. Then I noticed that they were only GIFs, no JPG.

Answer (score 1):

These should work (make sure $destination is defined)

```
find "$someDir" \( -iname \*.jpg -o -name \*.png -o -name \*.gif \) -exec echo hello {}
find "$someDir" \( -iname \*.jpg -o -name \*.png -o -name \*.gif \) -exec mv {} $destination \;
```

Comment: Exactly. No superfluous `sh -c`.